# Control the order Interceptors are executed

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, interceptor

How can I manage in what order Interceptors are executed?

I would like to have a general exception interceptor outermost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.First`, `.Last` or `.AtIndex()` to control interceptor ordering when declaring the interceptor reference, e.g.:

```
 container.Register(
    Component.For<ISomething>()
    .ImplementedBy<Something>()
    .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForKey("myinterceptor")).Last);
```

Or use `.Anywhere` if you don't care about ordering.

Comment: or if you need more dynamic control (which I infer from your question you don't) you can use `IInterceptorsSelector`

Comment: added to the docs: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-Interceptors-ProxyOptions.ashx?NS=Windsor#Ordering_interceptors_1